# My mp3player freezes when I eject it

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, shutdown

When I eject(or safely remove) or unplug my mp3player from the USB, the screen freezes and an "ok to disconnect" message remains on its screen. Then I have to reset my mp3player. However when I shutdown my computer while the my3player is mounted it doesn't freeze and everything works correctly. I know this is a problem with my mp3player. The question is how can I eject my mp3player normally without forcing to shutdown the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Some USB devices require an USB bus reset after unmounting a USB devices, which is done on Windows by default, but not on Linux.

Nowadays, nearly all (besides obviously Mint's) desktop environments use [`udisk`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/)'s `detach` capability to safely unmount and then "disconnect" USB devices.

As long as Mint doesn't do this, you can simply do `udisks --detach /dev/sdXX` to *properly* disconnect your MP3 player.

Comment: I did it. screen freezed again.

Comment: Why it unmounts correctly when i shoutdown the computer? What happens when i shutdown the computer? How can i take the same steps manually without shutting down?

Comment: What kind of MP3 player (brand, model) is it? What's your Kernel version (`uname -r`). What does `dmesg | tail -5` show after running `udisks --detach /dev/sdXX`. Does the command `udisks --detach /dev/sdXX` itself show any output?

Comment: Iriver T7. The kernel is 3.5.0-17-generic.  
`[23345.247487] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds  
[23345.247552] EXT3-fs (sda5): warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended  
[23345.247843] EXT3-fs (sda5): using internal journal  
[23345.247849] EXT3-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode  
[23405.735024] usb 2-1.5: >USB disconnect, device number 5  
`  
No the command itself doesn't show any output.

Comment: `udisks --detach /dev/sdb` Says: Detach failed: /dev/sdb is mounted.   
Then I run this command: `umount /media/saji/"New Volume"`   
Then I run this again `udisks --detach /dev/sdb`    
I ran `dmesg` after these commands.

Comment: Sure, you were supposed to run `udisks --detach /dev/sdb` *after* umounting. I wasn't really clear regarding this. Everything looks good so far, only your Kernel is quite old, so probably update it to something more recent (3.11.x or 3.12.x).